# Indexing mapping with hibernate search coupled with hibernate ORM special case

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-search

I have a mapping to do with hibernate search, that implies a lot of collection.

In class NatureBien I have the following method

```
public Collection<Cadastre> getCadastres() {
        List<Cadastre> resultats = new ArrayList<Cadastre>();
        for (AssietteCadastrale currAssiette : this.getAssiettes()) {
            for (SectionAssiette currSection : currAssiette.getSections()) {
                if (currSection != null) {
                    resultats.addAll(currSection.getCadastres());
                }
            }
        }

        // tri des cadastres
        Collections.sort(resultats);

        return resultats;
    }
```

I'am interesting in the indexing of Cadastre entity, some fields. For this, I start from NatureBien entity which I need to index. But how to say that, "Use the index embedded in Cadastre entity and when the fields indexed in Cadastre change/update then trigger the reindexing of this NatureBien". As you can see the access from NatureBien to Cadastre is not easy and we need to traverse several entities through collection or not.
From cadastre, the deeper relation, I have the collection of sectionAssiette, from sectionAssiette I have one AssietteCadastrale and from on AssietteCadastrale  I have the natureBien. So when I update a Cadastre, I should be able to reindex several NatureBien.

Cadastre class :

```
public Set<SectionAssiette> getSectionsAssiette() {
        return this.sectionsAssiette;
    }
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "cadastres2sections_assiette",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cadastres_fk", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sections_assiette_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    protected Set<SectionAssiette> sectionsAssiette = new HashSet<>();
```

SectionAssiette class :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "assiette_fk")
protected AssietteCadastrale assiette;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = Cadastre_.SECTIONS_ASSIETTE)
protected Set<Cadastre> cadastres = new HashSet<>();

public java.util.Set<Cadastre> getCadastres() {
        return this.cadastres;
    }
public AssietteCadastrale getAssiette() {
        return assiette;
    }
```

AssietteCadastrale class :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = SectionAssiette_.ASSIETTE)
    @OrderColumn(name = "assiette_cadastrale_sections_idx", nullable = false)
    protected List<SectionAssiette> sections = new ArrayList<>();
public NatureBien getNatureBien() {
        return this.natureBien;
    }
public List<SectionAssiette> getSections() {
        return this.sections;
    }
```

NatureBien class :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = AssietteCadastrale_.NATURE_BIEN, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @OrderColumn(name = "nature_bien_assiettes_idx", nullable = false)
    protected List<AssietteCadastrale> assiettes = new ArrayList<>();

public Collection<Cadastre> getCadastres() {
//see start of topic
}
public List<AssietteCadastrale> getAssiettes() {
        return this.assiettes;
    }
```

Of course, If I set @IndexingDependency(reindexOnUpdate = ReindexOnUpdate.NO) on getCadastres() method, all is working. But I may have bad indexed data, I wish to reindex the field cadastre of NatureBien "in live".

thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your post lacks a question, so I'm not sure what you want to know exactly. I will assume you want to know how to index `getCadastres()`.

You should have a look at [this section of the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-reindexing-derivedfrom).

Something like this should work:

```
@IndexedEmbedded
@IndexingDependency(derivedFrom = @ObjectPath( 
        @PropertyValue(propertyName = "assiettes"),
        @PropertyValue(propertyName = "sections"),
        @PropertyValue(propertyName = "cadastres")
))
public Collection<Cadastre> getCadastres() {
        List<Cadastre> resultats = new ArrayList<Cadastre>();
        for (AssietteCadastrale currAssiette : this.getAssiettes()) {
            for (SectionAssiette currSection : currAssiette.getSections()) {
                if (currSection != null) {
                    resultats.addAll(currSection.getCadastres());
                }
            }
        }

        // tri des cadastres
        Collections.sort(resultats);

        return resultats;
    }
```

Alternatively, you can put `@IndexedEmbedded` on `getAssiettes()`, `getSections()` and `getCadastres()`; with an [`includePaths` filter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexedembedded-filtering) you should be able to get the same result.